# Redis Sentinel C# Client

Tags: c#, redis, redis-sentinel

I've got 3 redis servers, 1 master & 2 slaves. Currently just the 1 sentinel running, which is monitoring them all well. It will promote whichever instance when required and is really smooth.

The problem i currently have is communicating with it from C#. From my googling, it would appear that only csredis supports the sentinel for retrieving slaves/masters. So using code like this...

```
//Create a manager, which has all the sentinels in it (this would have 3 when we go live)
RedisSentinelManager sentman = new RedisSentinelManager("localhost:26379");

//Get a slave, as these are read-only
sentman.GetSlave("mymaster", 100, 100);

//Get a master, for storing an object
sentman.GetMaster("mymaster", 100, 100);
```

This works, absolutely fine and the various responses change when i kill an instance. However, it's incredibly slow!

If i create the manager and try and get the slave 5 times, then it takes around 1second per slave request, which is crazy slow. What i have noticed, is that the very first request is very, very fast. See the code below...

```
//Try and get 5 slaves
for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i ++ )
{
    Stopwatch a = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    var slave = sentman.GetSlave("mymaster", 50, 50);

    if (slave == null)
        Console.WriteLine("Failed to get slave");

    Console.WriteLine("Took " + a.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString() + "ms to get " + slave.Host + ":" + slave.Port);
}
```

Here is the output...

```
Took 4ms to get localhost:6400
Took 844ms to get localhost:6400
Took 1007ms to get localhost:6400
Took 999ms to get localhost:6400
Took 994ms to get localhost:6400
```

Which is odd, the first one is 4ms! Then it's taking an age to get any subsequent clients. So i try another test, creating a new SentinelManager every loop item, is that faster? Nope, exactly the same. First one is very quick, then very very slow.

Am i using this library wrong, or have I found a bug? Going to try and grab the source and step through it...

Cheers guys...

---

Answer (score 1):

I've found the problem here, it's an issue with the client. In it's dispose method it's taking around 1s to dispose of some async objects.

Comment: Are you going to submit a pull request with your changes?

Comment: I submitted an issue, however my change was to strip all of the Async code out of the library completely, so not exactly a fix.